# Error Document not defined in IDE and not working in browser or jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html

I am following code from a book Javascript Novice to Ninja and the second javascript code gives me an error (document is not defined)

The error is in the IDE (Brackets). When trying it in a browser the page shows the HTML but the JS does not work. When putting it into jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/scrupply/xgotuyer/) it also does not work. What am I doing wrong? What did the book do wrong?

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var rainbow = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo","Violet"];

function change() {
    document.body.style.background = rainbow[Math.floor(7 * Math.random())];
}
button.addEventListener("Click", change);
```

The background should change colors according to the array that is being called. The only output is the HTML button. The actual error is "Document is not defined. [no-undef] for line 3 and line 7.

Comment: its `'click'` not `'Click'`

Comment: Other than what Daniel said, your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/hcuyxeq5/3/

Comment: "Click" is the displayed text on the button. Not part of the JS.

Comment: I got it to work in jsfiddle, but not in brackets. Still the document is not defined. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I thought that you were meaning the click me in the html. Thank you for your jsfiddle acdcjunior.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure - fiddle looks crazy on mobile, but suppose you are working on not loaded page - you should start a function by onload of body element or sometimes you can put a script next to an element. Default position is probably before body in head so body is not loaded yet, nor document.

This shortened version works even in mobile FF, but not in HTML display which do not run JS probably:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var rainbow = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"];

        function change() {
            document.body.style.background = rainbow[Math.floor(7 * Math.random())];
        }
        function worksAfterLoad() {
            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            button.addEventListener("click", change);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="worksAfterLoad()">
        <button id="button">Click Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE has nice and quick debugger (F12) where you can pause use breakpoint and inspect anything including document in watch window.